# Why the "+" operator is undefined? JAVA

Tags: java

I made this code in eclipse=

**Strart CLASS**(i made a mistace)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class strart {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Window object = new Window();

    object.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    object.setSize(300,250);
    object.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

**Window CLASS**

```
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import java.awt.TextField;
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
  import java.awt.TextField;
  import java.awt.Event.*;
  import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
  import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

  public class Window extends JFrame {
TextField kimeno = new TextField(25);
TextField dkimeno = new TextField(25);
TextField n1 = kimeno;
TextField n2 = dkimeno;
private JButton plus;
public Window()
{
    super("Math engine");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    plus = new JButton("+");
    plus.setFocusable(false);
    plus.addActionListener(new EnableButton());
    add(plus);
    add(kimeno);
    add(dkimeno);
}

public class EnableButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println(n1+n2);
    }

    }
  }
```

But i am still getting an error in line 32 of the Window class 
the error is "The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) java.awt.TextField, java.awt.TextField"

Comment: How would you define the operation?

Comment: You got sucked in by String swizzling.  If you say `"Some string" + someObject` then the compiler will coerce `someObject` to String by using `toString`.  But if you don't have a String in the expression it won't.  Simple fix is to code `println("" + n1 + n2)`.

Comment: @HotLicks that would display the object references...

Comment: @Reimeus - In this case, probably.  But that would be another question.

Comment: not even minimal understanding of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would it mean to add two `TextField` Objects? The + operator in Java can only be used with operands that are numbers or strings. (Well, that's simplifying it a bit you can look up the exact rules in the Java language specification.)

If you want to calculate the sum of two numeric strings stored in the TextFields (I assume integers) you can use something like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(n1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(n2.getText())
```

Of course, you should add some error handling.

Comment: and how to onvert the text in the text field  into number?

Answer (score 7):

The `+` operator makes no sense for `TextField` objects. You want

```
System.out.println(n1.getText() + n2.getText());
```

Comment: +1 but extra brownie points if you check nullness.

Comment: @chrylis they are package private, non-final, so there's plenty of opportunity to `null` them before a button is clicked.

Comment: Oh where have I heard that before?! Every time I witness a NullPointerException in a production system, echos from some developer saying "It will never be null" are still ringing around developer cyberspace.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
System.out.println(n1.getText() + n2.getText());
```

The '+' opperator when used with Strings will concatenate them together.

In this case you are not dealing with Strings, but TextField's, which have the .getText() function attached to get the String representation of their value.